# Can the R prompt be a time?

Tags: r

?option says this.

```
     ‘prompt’: a non-empty string to be used for R's prompt; should
          usually end in a blank (‘" "’).
```

Is it possible to make the prompt to include some dynamic stuffs, e.g., the current time?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the `taskCallbackManager` (https://developer.r-project.org/TaskHandlers.pdf). With `prompt` you can call the current time and save it. Example: `options("prompt"=format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S> "))`. But this is fixed with the time it was set.

The doc for the function `taskCallbackManager` has the rest:

```r
R> h <- taskCallbackManager()
R> h$add(function(expr, value, ok, visible) { 
+     options("prompt"=format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S> ")); 
+             return(TRUE) }, 
+     name = "simpleHandler")
[1] "simpleHandler"
07:25:42> a <- 2
07:25:48>
```

This registers a callback that gets evaluated after each command completes.

Comment: I tried to add this code to ~/.Rprofile. But the first prompt is not changed. The subsequent prompt is changed. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Also, another problem is the prompt is not updated when I just type Enter. I'd expect that the prompt should be updated just like in bash.

Comment: Can you provide your code?